# Consulting to or consulting for?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

What would be the correct usage of (to/for) in the following phrase?

> ... a small technology company specializing in consulting (to/for) dog owners

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use "for' and I think "a small technology company specialized in **consulting services for dog owners**" sounds better.